# BIND9 not starting due to apparmor error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dns

I have BIND version 9.19.16 installed on my Ubuntu server. However, it does not start the BIND service. When I try `systemctl start bind9` it takes a minute or so and then returns with the following error:

```
Job for named.service failed because a timeout was exceeded.
```

When I look at the status using `systemctl status bind9`, I am presented with:

```
● named.service - BIND Domain Name Server
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: activating (start) since Tue 2023-09-05 11:30:19 BST; 3s ago
       Docs: man:named(8)
   Main PID: 10461 (named)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 1096)
     Memory: 3.5M
     CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
             └─10461 /usr/sbin/named -f -u bind

Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: command channel listening on ::1#953
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: managed-keys-zone: loaded serial 135
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 2
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: zone 0.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: zone 127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: zone 255.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 1
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: all zones loaded
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: FIPS mode is disabled
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: running
Sep 05 11:30:19 ip-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx named[10461]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . is now trusted (acceptance timer complete)
```

No matter how long I wait, the status remains as activating. When I enter `journalctl -xe` I can see that there is an error with apparmor:

```
audit[10470]: AVC apparmor="DENIED" operation="sendmsg" profile="/usr/sbin/named" name="/run/systemd/notify" pid=10470 comm="named" requested_mask="w" denied_mask="w" fsuid=113 ouid=0
```

So I edit my `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` file to include the following line: `/run/systemd/notify w,` and restart both apparmor and BIND9 but I am still presented with the same error. Any idea what is wrong?

Comment: Did you `sudo apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` ?

Comment: @symcbean Just tried that and got this error: 'File /etc/apparmor.d/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named not found, skipping...'

Comment: Don't cut and paste stuff of the internet without at least reading first. I accidentally made what is a very obvious typo when copying and pasting - leaving it here as an object lesson.

Comment: @symcbean even the correct code doesn't fix the original problem

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this case is with wrong definition of profile in  `/etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named` file. Change the file in following way:

```
-profile named /usr/sbin/named flags=(attach_disconnected, complain) {
+profile /usr/sbin/named flags=(attach_disconnected) {
```

and run  `apparmor_parser -r /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.named`

More info about profiles in apparmor:
https://doc.opensuse.org/documentation/leap/security/html/book-security/cha-apparmor-profiles.html